# Github Simple Fork definition for newbie

Tags: github

I'm new to github and I'm trying to understand what a fork on Github is exactly?. Please help a newbie out. Tried reading on their blog but I get more confused .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A github fork is a clone of another repository which you can access and push your own commits to. Think of it as your own working copy hosted on github.

It's still associated with the origin repository, so you'll receive messages when new commits are pushed to it.

Also, after you pushed your own changes to your fork, you can ask the maintainer of the origin repository to update their repository with your changes, which is called a pull request.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response...ohh I see , so the original repository doesn't get altered with my commits unless they approve it somehow?

Comment: Exactly. Since you're not the original author, you can't change their code, but you can ask them to accept your changes. Just open your fork, click `Pull Requests` on the right-hand side and click `New pull request`.

Comment: I just saw: In your forked repository, there's a small `Compare` button just above the list of files on the right side. It opens the same view you can see from `New pull request`